# Prove if $E_1$ and $E_2$ are measurable, so is $E_1 \cap E_2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove if $E_1$ and $E_2$ are measurable, so is $E_1 \cap E_2$.

Definition of measurable is as follows: A subset $E$ of $X$ is called measurable whenever $\mu(A)=\mu(A \cap E)+\mu(A \cap E^c)$ holds for all $A$ subset of $X$.

To be a measure it must also satisfy the following properties:

1. $\mu(\emptyset)=0$
2. $\mu(A)\leq \mu(B)$ if $A \subset B$ (that is, $\mu$ is monotone)
3. $\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i \right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(E_i)$ holds for every sequence of subsets $E_i$ of $X$ (that is, $\mu$ is subadditive).

This question just appears to be a matter of using definitions but I am a little confused on the definitions of $\mu$ and how to go about proving this.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but do you mean to show that the set of $\mu$-measurable sets (where $\mu$ is an outer-measure) forms a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Everything after the second paragraph is irrelevant. Those properties listed pertain to the outer measure function and how it acts on elements of the collection of sets it is defined over, not the measure of any particular set.

Comment: HINT: Apply what you said in the second paragraph. Can you apply your definition to $E_1\cap E_2$ and rearrange the terms so you can apply the the assumptions that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are measurable?

Comment: @user112790 it's relevant if the true intention here is to prove that an outer measure is a measure over the (well-defined) $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets.

Comment: @JonathanY.  this is where my confusion lies, the textbook I am using has the notation I posted above but according to some of the research i've done, i believe you are correct. the different notation and defintions are confusing to me.

Comment: The natural way to prove this statement is to use the Caratheodory criterion in the OP's second paragraph.

Comment: @user112790 i will work on using Caraheodory's defintion and see what i can come up with. thanks

Comment: Remember that if $E_1$ is measurable then $E_1^C$ is measurable. Also recall that $E_1\cap E_2=E_1^C\cup E_2^C$.

Answer (score 7):

I think in the Chasky demonstration something is not right in the line where he asserts that $A \cap(E_2\cup E_1) \subseteq (A\cap E_2)\cup (A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2)$, or at least it seems false to me but I could be wrong.

I think an easier one could be the following demonstration, where I use m instead of mu for the outer measure.
So  to say that $E_1\cap E_2$ is measurable, you just need to show that for any set A subset of R
$$m(A)\geq m(A\cap (E_1\cap E_2)) + m(A\cap(E_1\cap E_2)^c)$$

Let's take A as any subset of R. Since $E_1$, is measurable, it means that:
$$ m(A)=m(A\cap E_1) + m(A\cap E_1^c)  \tag a $$
Now since $E_2$ is measurable too, you have that
$$ m(A\cap E_1)=m(A\cap E_1\cap E_2) + m(A\cap E_1\cap E_2^c) \tag b$$ and also that
$$ m(A\cap E_1^c)=m(A\cap E_1^c\cap E_2) + m(A\cap E_1^c\cap E_2^c) \tag c$$
Now substituting $(b)$ and $(c)$ in $(a)$ you get the following:
$$ m(A)=m(A\cap E_1\cap E_2) + m(A\cap E_1\cap E_2^c)+m(A\cap E_1^c\cap E_2) + m(A\cap E_1^c\cap E_2^c) \tag d$$
Now it is easy  to prove that the following holds:
$$\begin{align}(A\cap E_1\cap E_2^c)&\cup(A\cap E_1^c\cap E_2)\cup (A\cap E_1^c\cap E_2^c)\\&= A\cap((E_1\cap E_2^c)\cup(E_1^c\cap E_2)\cup(E_1^c\cap E_2^c))\\ &=A\cap(E_1^c \cup E_2^c)=A\cap (E_1\cap E_2)^c\end{align}$$
So by sub-additive you have that
$$ m(A\cap (E_1\cap E_2)^c) \leq m(A\cap E_1\cap E_2^c)+m(A\cap E_1^c\cap E_2) + m(A\cap E_1^c\cap E_2^c) \tag e$$

Substituting $(e)$ in $(d)$ you have the final result

$$\begin{align} m(A)&=m(A\cap E_1\cap E_2) + m(A\cap E_1\cap E_2^c)+m(A\cap E_1^c\cap E_2) + m(A\cap E_1^c\cap E_2^c) \\&\geq m(A\cap E_1\cap E_2) + m(A\cap(E_1\cap E_2)^c)\end{align}$$
I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are measurable, then by definition $E_1^c $ and $E_2^c$ are measurable and $E_1^c \cup E_2^c$ is measurable (I will prove this below) and hence

$$ ( E_1^c \cup E_2^c )^c = E_1 \cap E_2 \; \text{must be measurable}$$

By using your definition, it is trivial to see that the complement of a measurable set is measurable.

Now, we show $E_1 \cup E_2 $ is measurable. By hypothesis, since $E_1$ is measurable, take $A \subseteq X$, such that

$$ \mu(A) = \mu(A \cap E_1) + \mu(A \cap E_1^c) $$

Now, since $E_2$ is measurable, then

$$ \mu(A \cap E_1^c) = \mu(A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2) + \mu(A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2^c)$$

Now, combine these two equation to obtain

$$ \mu(A) = \mu(A \cap E_1) + \mu(A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2) + \mu(A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2^c)$$

Now, since $A \cap  (E_2 \cup E_1) \subseteq (A \cap E_2) \cup (A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2)$, then

$$ \mu(A) = \mu(A \cap E_1) + \mu(A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2) + \mu(A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2^c) \geq $$

$$ \geq \mu(A \cap (E_1 \cup E_2) + \mu(A \cap (E_1 \cup E_2)^c )$$

by monotonocity and subadditivty. Then, notice by definition $E_1 \cup E_2 $ must be measurable and your problem is solved.

Comment: is it not nececessary to show that the countable union of measurable sets is measurable? or to show finite additivity for disjoint measurable sets in Lebesgue measure?

Comment: No. We are simply showing that the intersection of two measurable sets is again measurable. You are confusing properties of a measure function with what it means to be for a set to be measurable.